# php $post_data to be user generated

Tags: php, html, forms, post, curl

OK thanks for the comments.

**The objective:** I have an external site which has a search form. I want to input on their form using my own form and return their page response on mine using cURL.  Here's the latest edited code I have:

test.html file:

```
<FORM ACTION='submit.php' METHOD='POST'>
<input type="text" name="username" value="Name">
</FORM>
```

submit.php file:

```
$post_data['usernamet'] = $_POST;
$post_data['action'] = 'Submit';
```

Problem is it submits fine but the external site seems to return results which only include the word "Array" rather than the actual search term. I've echo'd the username to see what it outputs and it always states the search term with "Array" on the end.

Comment: Look at any PHP example anywhere and your mistake with regard to how to read from `$_POST` will become obvious.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of `submit.php` do one of these: `$post_data = $_POST`

Comment: Thanks I think editing that line of yours to this helped: $post_data['username'] = $_POST;